# How to configure ActiveMQ JCA connector in JBoss to use XA connections?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, activemq-classic

On JBoss 5.1.0 I have Datasource (PostgreSQL 8.3.11) configured using *-ds.xml (standard jboss DS). It uses XADataSource ([PGXADataSource](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/xa/PGXADataSource.html)). I also have ActiveMQ broker (right now it runs as in-VM, under JBoss, but it will be on separate server latter).

What I want to do is to make ActiveMQ Connection Factory and Datasource to participate in XA Transactions. For example, I want to update DB record and send a JMS message as a UOW. You get the idea.

I configured PGXADataSource in my-pg-ds.xml and it works (I can trace execution all the way to [PGXAConnection's start method](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/development/privateapi/org/postgresql/xa/PGXAConnection.html#start%28javax.transaction.xa.Xid,%20int%29)). I have tried to configure [ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory.html) directly in Spring (I am using Spring 3.0.2.RELEASE), but this does not work, because in this case Spring transaction manager (I use annotation  to let Spring configure [JtaTransactionManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/jta/JtaTransactionManager.html) which simply delegates all the work to Jboss transaction manager) does not enlist XAResource for given [ActiveMQXAConnection](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/activemq-core/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQXAConnection.html). Whenever I try to send a message I get an exception JMSException saying "Session's XAResource has not been enlisted in a distributed transaction." thrown from [ActiveMQXASession](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-core/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/ActiveMQXASession.java).

Since that did not work, I have switched to JCA configuration of ActiveMQ ConnectionFactory (based on [this](http://activemq.apache.org/integrating-apache-activemq-with-jboss.html) document) and it works for regular [ConnectionFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jms/ConnectionFactory.html), but I do not understand how can I configure it to use XAConnectionFactory. It seems like [Resource Adapter](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-ra/) simply does not have proper ManagedConnectionFactory, ManagedConnection, etc. implementations for XA connection factory.

Am I missing something or do I have no choice but to write XA wrappers for resource adapter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. Jboss includes JCA connector for any JMS factory (supports both types of transactions: XA and local). It is located in /server//deploy/jms-ra.rar. Here is how I configured it.

First, `activemq-jms-ds.xml` file that goes into deploy directory next to jms-ra.rar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE connection-factories
    PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD JBOSS JCA Config 1.5//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-ds_1_5.dtd">

<connection-factories>
    <mbean code="org.jboss.jms.jndi.JMSProviderLoader"
       name="jboss.messaging:service=JMSProviderLoader,name=ActiveMQJMSProvider">
        <attribute name="ProviderName">ActiveMQJMSProvider</attribute>
        <attribute name="ProviderAdapterClass">org.jboss.jms.jndi.JNDIProviderAdapter</attribute>
        <attribute name="FactoryRef">java:/activemq/XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
        <attribute name="QueueFactoryRef">java:/activemq/XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
        <attribute name="TopicFactoryRef">java:/activemq/XAConnectionFactory</attribute>
    </mbean>

    <tx-connection-factory>
        <jndi-name>JmsXAConnectionFactory</jndi-name>
        <xa-transaction/>
        <rar-name>jms-ra.rar</rar-name>
        <connection-definition>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory</connection-definition>
        <config-property name="JmsProviderAdapterJNDI" type="java.lang.String">java:/ActiveMQJMSProvider</config-property>
    </tx-connection-factory>
</connection-factories>
```

This tells Jboss to look into jms-ra.rar and find adapter that can provide managed connection factory for `org.jboss.resource.adapter.jms.JmsConnectionFactory`. Internally jms adapter depends on JmsProviderAdapter, which is used to store JNDI names of connection factories (in my config all names are the same).

I use mbean tag to configure JMSProviderLoader (this is copied from one of internal JBoss configs). Now, all I have to do is somehow create an instance of my XA connection factory and bind it to `java:/activemq/XAConnectionFactory`. There are several ways to do it (implement MBean wrapper, for example).

Since I am Jboss 5 I used microcontainer (which is likely to work in Jboss 6). I added `activemq-jms-jboss-beans.xml` file into `deployers`direcotry:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<deployment xmlns="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">
    <!-- Define a Jndi binding aspect/annotation that exposes beans via jndi
        when they are registered with the kernel.
    -->
    <aop:lifecycle-configure xmlns:aop="urn:jboss:aop-beans:1.0"
        name="DependencyAdvice"
        class="org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.aspects.jndi.JndiLifecycleCallback"
        classes="@org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.aspects.jndi.JndiBinding"
        manager-bean="AspectManager"
        manager-property="aspectManager">
    </aop:lifecycle-configure>

    <bean name="ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory">
        <annotation>@org.jboss.aop.microcontainer.aspects.jndi.JndiBinding(name="activemq/XAConnectionFactory", aliases={"java:/activemq/XAConnectionFactory"})</annotation>
        <property name="brokerURL">vm://localhost</property>
    </bean>
</deployment>
```

I create a `ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory` bean. To bind it to JNDI, I annotate it with JndiBinding annotation. For this annotation to work, we need JndiLifecycleCallback. As far as I can tell, JndiLifecycleCallback is called on every bean created by microcontainer and checks for JndiBinding annotation on that bean.

Comment: Where do I need to set user name and password ?  is it attribue or property ? what is name of that ( start with caps or small )