# ActiveMQ 5, JBoss 7 and XA transactions

Tags: java, transactions, activemq-classic, jboss7.x, xa

I've found this article to configure ActiveMQ in JBoss 5 : 
[How to configure ActiveMQ JCA connector in JBoss to use XA connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3167905/how-to-configure-activemq-jca-connector-in-jboss-to-use-xa-connections)

But I'm using JBoss AS 7 and can't figure out how to make it enlist my Jmstransaction in the global XA transaction ...

Does anyone have already made this work ?